# Is it possible/allowed to use iOS as a gateway between Bluetooth device and cloud (when app in background)

Tags: ios, web-services, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

I would like to use an iOS device as a gateway between BLE device and cloud when app is in background. Is this (a) possible and (b) according to Apple's guidelines?

```
Architecture:

BLE device <-> iOS <-> Cloud
```

The scenario is as follows:

1. cloud sends message to BLE device
2. BLE device sends response (result) to cloud

**solution for step 1:**

As far as I understand 'background notifications' [1] can be used to trigger an action on the iOS device when app is in background. Is one allowed to send a message to BLE device in this context?
Is there a more generic solution, that works for android and iOS?

**solution for step 2:**

iOS 'Core Bluetooth' allows background processing [2]. So once the result is available the iOS app would be triggered again. In this context, is it allowed to open a connection to cloud (RESTful API, Azure Service Bus, Azure IoT Hub, or similar) to forward the result?

[1] https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

[2] https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes! it is possible, i created an article that shows how to make an iPhone gateway and connect to another board (ESP32) using BLE.

What i did was i first connected to Google Cloud IoT Core using MQTT,once the iPhone was connected i scanned for the board using Core Bluetooth. Then it would connect to the ESP32, the ESP32 would send the data to the iPhone and the iPhone would publish this data to PubSub.

[Controlling Your Phone From The Cloud](https://medium.com/swlh/controlling-your-phone-from-the-cloud-f075b75858c9)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It is possible.
I am agree with your 2nd solutions.

bluetooth-central—The app communicates with Bluetooth low energy peripherals using the Core Bluetooth framework.
bluetooth-peripheral—The app shares data using the Core Bluetooth framework.